# Selenium python TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when finding element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable" when I execute this code:

```
iframe=driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://pianomarvel.com/uploads/editSlicings/85810')]"));
```

Why?

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks

I tried

```
iframe=driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://pianomarvel.com/uploads/editSlicings/85810')]"));
```

I was expecting it to return an iframe, but instead it returned an error.

I'm trying to identify an iframe.  I have two iframes they are both the same class.  They have differing src, so I wanted to identify them that way

Comment: give a url and point what exactly you need to fetch from it?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of doing this would be:
`xpath` should be in small case

```
iframe=driver.find_element(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://pianomarvel.com/uploads/editSlicings/85810')]"));
```

OR

```
iframe = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://pianomarvel.com/uploads/editSlicings/85810')]")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several syntax errors in this line `iframe=driver.find_element(By.XPATH("//iframe[contains(@src,'https://pianomarvel.com/uploads/editSlicings/85810')]"));`
Try this instead:

```py
iframe=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'https://pianomarvel.com/uploads/editSlicings/85810')]")
```

Comment: this code worked.  However I got an error message:  selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:  Here is the reference to the iframe:  <iframe class="popup" src="https://pianomarvel.com/uploads/editSlicings/85810"></iframe>.  I have seen the popup class on another iframe, and the src differentiates the two.

Comment: We need to see all your code including the link to the page you working on.

Comment: Here is the link to the page:  https://pianomarvel.com/uploads

Comment: I need to login there. Please share ALL your code including the credentials. Otherwise we can't help

Comment: Please share it inside the question, not here

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!  I was able to get it to work by issuing driver.switch_to.default_content() before I issued the above command

Comment: great! in case the issue is resolved now you can accept the answer to indicate the question is resolved